# Почему возникает ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, исключения

постоянно получаю ошибку, когда пытаюсь добавить объекты на карту.
Гугл мне не дал ясности, стек оверфлоу я тоже, не понял, что пытается донести.
Единственное, что понял, одновременно читаю и записываю в этот список.

p.s. прошу прощения за орфографию

```
private void addGeoObjectsToMap() {
    List<? extends GeoObject> list = getCurrentPageObjectsList();
    if (list != null) {
        for (GeoObject obj : list) {
            addUserMarker(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: javadoc про `CurrentModificationException` и про списки читать пробовали?

Comment: @a_gura, да читал, но как правильно реализовать, я так и не понял

Comment: @metalurgus беда в том, что я его именно скопировал :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ConcurrentModificationException` выбрасывается тогда, когда вы пытаетесь вставлять или удалять из коллекции элементы во время перебора элементов этой коллекции. Это потенциально может привести к некорректному поведению итератора (возвращению неверного следующего элемента или некорректному результату метода `hasNext()`), поэтому все стандартные коллекции предпочитают сразу пресечь подобное поведение.

Если вам необходимо удалять элементы из коллекции во время перебора её элементов, то вам следует использовать явный перебор при помощи итератора:

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<String> strIter = strList.iteraror();
while (strIter.hasNext()) {
    String str = strIter.next();
    if (/* condition */) {
        strIter.remove();
    }
}
```

Вставка элментов в коллекцию во время перебора её элементов стандартными коллекциями не поддерживается.

**UPD**

> дело в том, что мне **не** нужно одновременно читать и записывать в коллекцию

Будем считать, что *не* - это опечатка и вам на самом деле *нужно* это делать. В таких случаях делают копию исходной коллекции. Итерация идёт по исходной коллекции, а вставка и удаление - из копии. После завершения цикла исходную коллекцию заменяют на новую.

Comment: @fori1ton, дело в том, что мне не нужно одновременно читать и записывать в коллекцию. Но как правильно сделать не знаю

Comment: >  дело в том, что мне _не_ нужно одновременно читать и записывать в коллекцию

Будем считать, что _не_ - это опечатка и вам на самом деле _нужно_ это делать. В таких случаях делают копию исходной коллекции. Итерация идёт по исходной коллекции, а вставка и удаление - из копии. После завершения цикла исходную коллекцию заменяют на новую.