# ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, коллекции

Здравствуйте! В  [данном куске кода](http://pastebin.com/MnrsQMeg) появляется исключение. причем, после 1-го вызова метода из return-а. Вроде бы коллекция получает новый итератор и работает с ним, но что-то идет не так.

Comment: дополните вопрос примером кода. не нужно публиковать его на сторонних ресурсах, сайт позволяет это делать на нем.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ConcurrentModificationException](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/404549/concurrentmodificationexception)

Answer (score 2):

Вы удаляете или изменяете элементы, делая проход по коллекции итератором. Используйте вместо итератора другой метод прохода (например, простой цикл, кроме *for each*).

Нельзя использовать *Iterator* и, в это же время, добавлять или удалять элементы из коллекции. *[ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)* как раз таки и говорит, что Вы параллельно модифицируете коллекцию.

Аналогичная ошибка выскочит, если использовать цикл *for each*, изменяя в нем элементы. Для этого подходит или `do while`, или простой `for`.

Comment: да, спасибо, переделал. Но где удаление было то? При waves = tempWaves? Но ведь итератор то новый всегда был

Comment: @ОлегРоздайбеда, прошу прощения, не полностью написал. Добавление, по смыслу, приводит к аналогичному результату. Я сталкивался только с удалением, поэтому о нем и написал :).

Comment: да, я это знаю, но где добавление то было? я же все новые объекты добавляю в совсем другую коллекцию, не ту, у которой получил итератор

Comment: @ОлегРоздайбеда, в данном куске кода — не вижу. А вот за пределами метода точно где-то модифицируется. Сделайте поиск по совпадениям на `iter.`.

Comment: нет, за пределами этого куска кода iter больше никак не используется

Comment: @ОлегРоздайбеда, покажите весь код класса, чтобы я мог его запустить.