# ConcurrentModificationException при удалении элемента из ArrayList с помощью итератора

Tags: java, arraylist

Есть код:

```
ParentNomen parentItem = parentNavList.get(nav_view.getChildAdapterPosition(itemView));
Iterator<ParentNomen> iter = parentNavList.iterator();
List<ParentNomen>subList = parentNavList.subList(parentNavList.indexOf(parentItem) + 1, parentNavList.size());
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    ParentNomen nexElem = iter.next();
    Iterator<ParentNomen> subIter = subList.iterator();
    while (subIter.hasNext()) {
        ParentNomen subNextElem = subIter.next();
        if (nexElem.getCode().equals(subNextElem.getCode())) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь `parentItem` - тот элемент списка `ArrayList<ParentNomen>`, по которому кликнул пользователь. Дальше я помещаю в `subList` те элементы списка, которые находятся после `parentItem`, а потом хочу их удалить, но вылетает исключение:

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:62)
>   at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:201)
>   at ua.com.liverpoll.client1c.NomenActivity$NavAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(NomenActivity.java:280)

Не могу понять что не так, здесь же все на итераторах, почему вылетает  `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ConcurrentModificationException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/404549/concurrentmodificationexception)

Comment: @iksuy, нет, там с помощью for (GeoObject obj : list), при таком проходе метод next итератора вызывается после remove, у меня же наоборот, ситуация другая.

Comment: @Regent, возможно наставил костылей, покажите как правильно, цель такая, есть коллекция "а,b,c,d,e", пользователь кликает по любому из элементов, например b, нужно удалить все что после него, а именно "c,d,e"

Comment: Отлично помогли....

Comment: @Regent, извините, думал что просто решили перенаправить на другую тему, спасибо Вам огромное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConcurrentModificationException` здесь возникает потому, что оба итератора хранят в себе (`expectedModCount`) ожидаемую версию модификации одного и того же, исходного списка (`modCount` этого списка).
Соответственно, когда происходит удаление элемента с помощью одного из итераторов, то `modCount` исходного списка меняется, и если в этом итераторе `expectedModCount` меняется на новую версию модификации списка (`modCount`), то во втором итераторе остаётся старое значение (`expectedModCount` равен старому значению `modCount`), что и приводит к возникновению исключения.

---

Просто удалить все элементы, следующие за данным, из списка можно с помощью связки `subList` и `clear`:

```
int index = parentNavList.indexOf(parentItem);
parentNavList.subList(index + 1, parentNavList.size()).clear();
```