# ConcurrentModificationException и Хешмап

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Здравствуйте кидает Exception `ConcurrentModificationException` на этой строчке `for (Transaction t : c.getTransactions())`(64 строчка) на 2 итерации. Саму суть ошибки понимаю - случается она тогда, когда в цикле происходит удаление элементов итератора. Пытался remove изменить на `removeIF`, но ошибка та же.Это уникальный вопрос, потому что он возникает, когда все требования по его решению соблюдены.

```
private static void iteration() {
        Integer n = 1;
        Integer k = 1;
        Double maxProfit;
        Integer clusterInd;
        while (k > 0) {
            System.out.println("Итерация " + n);
            n++;
            k = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<clusters.size();i++) {
                Cluster c = clusters.get(i);
                for (Transaction t : c.getTransactions()) {//ошибку кидает здесь на 2 итерации
                    maxProfit = profit();
                    clusterInd = -1;
                    c.deleteTransaction(t);
                    int j = 0;
                    for (Cluster cl : clusters) {
                        if (j != i) {
                            cl.addTransaction(t);
                            Double p = profit();
                            if (p > maxProfit) {
                                maxProfit = p;
                                clusterInd = j;
                            }
                            cl.deleteTransaction(t);
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                    if (clusterInd == -1){
                        clusters.get(i).addTransaction(t);
                    }else {
                        k++;
                        clusters.get(clusterInd).addTransaction(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(k);
    }
```

**Функция, в которой происходит удаление транзакции:**

```
public void deleteTransaction(Transaction m) {
        if (this.count > 0) {
            String[] trans = m.getTrans();
            for (String s : trans) {
                this.square--;
                if (freq.containsKey(s)) {
                    if (freq.get(s) > 0) {
                        this.freq.put(s, freq.get(s) - 1);
                        if (this.freq.get(s) == 0) {
                            this.width--;
                            freq.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(s));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            this.count--;
            if (this.count > 0) {
                this.height = (double) this.square / this.width;
            } else {
                this.height = 0.0;
            }
            transactions.removeIf(m::equals);
        }
    }
```

**Логи:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:893)
    at com.lab6.ClopeAlgorithm.iteration(ClopeAlgorithm.java:64)
    at com.lab6.ClopeAlgorithm.main(ClopeAlgorithm.java:96)
```

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` можно словить лишь в том случае, если во время перебора `forEach, Iterator`: удалить, добавить, либо еще сделать какую либо операцию по изменению элементов. Она приведет к ошибке.

Comment: And, спасибо кэп. Только я ещё знаю как она возникает и что?

Comment: Не понял вопрос.На сколько помню там есть проверка.
`int mod=correctMod;
if(mod != correctMod) ConcurrentModificationException;` - Чтобы избежать ошибки, нужно работать через объект итератора, а не обращаться на прямую или использовать синхронизацию.

Comment: @And я так и делал. Там на самом деле есть 2 счетчика. Один отвечает за модификацию, другой там еще на что- то отвечает. И при удалении проверяется эти 2 счетчика. Они типо должны быть равны.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ConcurrentModificationException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/404549/concurrentmodificationexception)

Comment: @Hivemaster не дубликат. потому что суть ошибки я знаю , но она у меня все равно вылетела. Вот в чем отличие моего вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создадим небольшую мапу:

```
final HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", "1");
map.put("2", "2");
map.put("3", "3");
```

Следующие выражения выбьют ошибку:

**Java 8+:**

```
map.entrySet().stream().filter((i) -> ("3".equals(i.getKey()))).forEachOrdered((i) -> {
    map.remove(i.getKey());
});
```

**Java < 8:**

```
for (Entry<Object, Object> i : map.entrySet()) {
    if ("2".equals(i.getKey())) {
         map.remove(i.getKey());
    }
}
```

Выражения, которые не выдадут ошибок:
Работает только на 1 удаление, если добавить еще один `if` для удаления, выдаст ошибку `NoSuchElementException`

```
final Iterator<Entry<Object, Object>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if ("2".equals(i.next().getKey())) {
       i.remove();
    }
}
```

Если хотим удалить два и более элемента, можно использовать:

```
while (i.hasNext()) {
    switch ((String) i.next().getKey()) {
        case"2":
        case"3":
            i.remove();
        break;                 
    }
}
```

Для удаления, добавления, изменения, лучше использовать `switch`:

```
final Map<Object, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.put("1", "1");
map.put("2", "2");
map.put("3", "3");
map.put("4", "5");
final Iterator<Entry<Object, Object>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    switch ((String) i.next().getKey()) {
        case "3":
            i.remove();
            map.put("5", "5");
            final Iterator<Entry<Object, Object>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                if ("2".equals((String) it.next().getKey())) {
                    it.remove();
                    map.put("5", "5");
                    map.put("6", "6");
                    map.remove(map.get("1"));

                }
            }
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(map); // {4=5, 5=5, 6=6}
```

Но опять-же у этого всего есть побочные эффекты.
Если в хранилище залетел какой-то объект, во время:

```
while (i.hasNext()) {
    switch((String)i.next().getKey()) {
       //.....
    }
}
```

Получим `ConcurrentModificationException`.
В вашем случае можно использовать подобно `mutex`.

```
synchronized(map) {
   //....
}
```

Тогда можно будет не бояться, что залетает.

Comment: Исключение `ConcurrentModification` не связано с многопоточностью и `synchronized` не поможет.

Comment: @Hivemaster, синхронизацию использывать на мапы: 
 `ConcurrentHashMap`, `HashMap`, так как напрямую можно работать из `Collections.synchronizedMap` к примеру. И чтобы при добавлении удаление, пока не будет доступен, не выполнится.

Comment: Это имеет смысл в многопоточном коде, но как синхронизация поможет избежать `ConcurrentModificationException` в однопоточном, как у автора вопроса? Я не понимаю, чем вообще ваш ответ может помочь.

Comment: @Hivemaster раз автор отметил его решением, значит чем-то помог.

Comment: @Hivemaster, так избежим, итератор не будет задействован при блокировке коллекции.  - код придется конечно подправить, что он наверно уже и сделал.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это здорово, но было бы ещё неплохо, если бы другие пользователи с такой же проблемой тоже смогли воспользоваться ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо цикла foreach используйте явный итератор и его метод [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--).

Comment: removeIf я это и делал.

Comment: начиная с 8 явы можно использовать removeIf

Comment: `Iterator.remove()` и `Collection.removeIf()` - это не одно и то же.

Comment: Сейчас попробую исправить.

Comment: пишу так:  for (  Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = freq.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                                if (it.next().getKey().equals(s)) {
                                    it.remove();
                                }
                            }
идея говорит - меняй на removeIf

Comment: Хорошо, что она так говорит, значит электронные болваны ещё не научились полноценно оценивать контекст, и есть шанс в ближайшие годы не лишиться работы.

Comment: Можно этим придуркам написать, но я думаю они сами вкурсе и ржут сейчас с нас

Comment: все равно та же ошибка. Исправил в 2 местах где удаление у меня происходит

Comment: Значит есть ещё места, в которых происходит изменение итерируемой коллекции не через итератор.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78227/discussion-between--and-sergey-gornostaev).

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали решение:
Изменить  `for (Transaction t : c.getTransactions())` на

```
for (int i=0;i<clusters.size();i++) { 
 Cluster c = clusters.get(i); 
 List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>(c.getTransactions()); 
 for (Transaction t : transactions) { 
... 
} 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Foreach – это механизм для работы с элементами коллекции, а не с самой коллекцией. Использование foreach для модификации коллекции – это уже не правильно. А писать костыли и велосипеды, чтобы «расширить возможности» конструкции языка – и вовсе плохая затея. Этот подход сломает возможность заменить реализацию А на реализацию Б без танцев с бубном и переписывания всего кода, где коллекция модифицировалась в foreach.

Вот один из классических подходов работы с итераторами:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
  if (it.next() % 2 == 0) {
    it.remove();
  }
}
```

Взято отсюда:

https://habr.com/post/325426/#comment_10149968