# Смена значение переменной полностью изменяет результат работы программы

Tags: java

Вот код, который я написал. Он не проходит валидацию, но не в этом дело. Дело в том, что меняя имена в мапе, полностью изменяется результат работы программы. Попробуйте удалить первую букву в aStark. При том, что ни в каком варианте, данный Старк не удаляется, хотя родился летом. Мистика или я не знаю чего-то фундаментального про map.

```
package com.javarush.task.task08.task0816;

    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.*;



public class Solution {
public static HashMap<String, Date> createMap() throws ParseException {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    HashMap<String, Date> map = new HashMap<String, Date>();
    map.put("Stallone", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
    map.put("Quibern", df.parse("MAY 4 1971"));
    map.put("aStark", df.parse("JUNE 21 1981"));
    map.put("Lannister", df.parse("NOVEMBER 15 1992"));
    map.put("Barateon", df.parse("MARCH 12 1975"));
    map.put("Tyrell", df.parse("APRIL 23 1989"));
    map.put("Martell", df.parse("FEBRUARY 4 2000"));
    map.put("Snow", df.parse("JANUARY 31 2002"));
    map.put("Bolton", df.parse("MAY 4 1977"));
    map.put("Sivort", df.parse("AUGUST 1 1974"));
    return map;

    //напишите тут ваш код
}

public static void removeAllSummerPeople(HashMap<String, Date> map) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Date>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        String date = iterator.next().getValue().toString();
        if(date.contains("Ju")  || date.contains("Aug")){
            //System.out.println(date);
            map.remove(iterator.next());
            System.out.println("kill " + date);
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        HashMap<String, Date> map = Solution.createMap();
        removeAllSummerPeople(map);
        for(Map.Entry<String, Date> pair : map.entrySet())
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакой мистики у вас нет, ваш код делает ровно то, что вы написали.

Во-первых, внутри `while (iterator.hasNext())` вы дважды вызываете `iterator.next()`, то есть за одну итерацию `while` вы перебираете два элемента. Вероятно, вы ожидаете, что `iterator.next()` в этой строке:

```
String date = iterator.next().getValue().toString();
```

и в этой:

```
map.remove(iterator.next());
```

вернет вам одно и то же, но это не так.

Во-вторых, `map.remove(iterator.next());` - удаление в `map` происходит по ключу, ключом у вас является `String`, `iterator.next()` вам возвращает `Map.Entry<>`, если вы работаете в IDE, она вас наверняка об этом предупредить должна была. То есть эта строка ничего не делает по сути в вашем случае.

В третьих, модифицировать коллекции и контейнеры во время прохода по ним нельзя, вы получите `ConcurrentModificationException`. В принципе, можно догадаться почему это произойдет, но если непонятно, то можете почитать ответы, например, на эти вопросы:

[Вопрос про ConcurrentModificationException 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/404549/concurrentmodificationexception)

[Вопрос про ConcurrentModificationException 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835695/concurrentmodificationexception-%D0%B8-%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BF/835735)

Итого, исправив все ошибки, ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry<String, Date> e = iterator.next();
    String dateString = e.getValue().toString();
    if(dateString.contains("Ju")  || dateString.contains("Aug")){
        //System.out.println(date);
        iterator.remove();
        System.out.println("kill " + dateString);
    }
}
```

**UPD**

> А каким образом Stark / aStark на это все влияют?

Ну это уже чистое стечение обстоятельств

Это происходит из-за того, что описано в "во-первых" выше. Поскольку один ключ меняется, элементы в `HashMap` лежат уже в другом порядке, в случае с `aStark` так совпадает, что когда `iterator.next()` возвращает последний элемент, то следующим вызывается метод `hasNext()` у этого итератора, а в случае с `Stark` после последнего элемента программа входит в блок `if`, где вызывается вновь `next()`, а элементов больше нет, бросается `NoSuchElementException`, которое отлавливается в пустом `catch` блоке, программа выводит два `kill` и успешно завершается.

Comment: А каким образом ``Stark`` / ``aStark`` на это все влияют?

Comment: @Эникейщик, дополнил

Comment: Понятно. (5букв)