# ArrayList, логика цикла for

Tags: java

Всем привет, объясните пожалуйста юному программисту, почему при выполнении этого кода 10 под нулевым индексом выводится, если я удаляю её первой же командой в цикле for, и по логике вещей, даже если она выводится, то и остальные должны так же выводиться, ан нет, нихрена, почему так???

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arraylist {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(10);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);

    for(Integer i : numbers) {
        numbers.remove(0);
        System.out.println(i);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Нельзя менять массив, который обходите, смотрите ConcurrentModificationException https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/404549/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-concurrentmodificationexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ты хочешь чтобы первый элемент был удален, то сначала надо его удалить до перебора элементов в цикле.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arraylist {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(10);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);
    numbers.add(100500);

numbers.remove(0);
    for(Integer i : numbers) {
        
        System.out.println(i);

    }
}

}
```

Тут в статье [описание работы с ArrayList](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1935-udalenie-ehlementa-iz-spiska-arraylist) описана ситуация почему нельзя одновременно перебирать циклом for:each и править коллекцию одновременно.

Answer (score 0):

Значение 10 потому что уже записалась в переменную i. Вы её инициализируете при объявлении первым же int-ом листа. Вынесите удаление перед циклом и все будет как вы хотели. Редактирование коллекции во время итерации запрещено

Comment: Нет, я специально добавил другие значения, чтоб увидеть логику, но логики я все равно не понял, можете пожалуйста чуть подробнее?

Comment: Почему другие не записываются в переменную i?

Comment: Integer i : numbers - вот тут переменной присваивается значение листа под нулевым индексом. То что вы редактируетн коллекцию на переменную не влияет на этой итерации, она Уже на первом ходу в объявлении получила  значение нулевого индекса

Comment: Так уберите remove

Comment: А сможете объяснить, почему тогда выводится элемент под индексом, если он сначала удаляется? С другими элементами точно такой же алгоритм(по видимому) происходит, но они уже не выводятся

Comment: @SALUTE так вам уже все объяснили, куда ещё яснее. Дальше не работает потому что ошибка итерации происходит из-за редактирования коллекции, try Block ом окружите и ловите ошибку ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: Да, я понял, редактировать и перебирать нельзя одновременно, но всё таки интересен сам алгоритм, почему происходит именно так, что первый элемент выводится, хоть он и так же удаляется, ровно как и другие элементы

Comment: Вы видимо вообще не читали, что я вам написал. Я ж расписал вам все. У вас в структуре for each в объявлении переменой i тут же происходит присваивание первого значения коллекции, потом уже идёт само тело цикла и в теле цикла на первой итерации идёт удаление, но до этого в переменную уже добавили это значение, ну скопировали его уже в i, что тут не ясно может быть

Comment: Вот как только  программа доходит до сюда for(Integer i : numbers), тут же в i копируется значение нулевого индекса, а удаляет вы из первоисточник, из листа, из переменной то вы не удаляете